# How to redirect to a file in multiple way in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a CSV. I am trying to write the header and an arbitrary percentage of lines to one file, and the header and the rest of the lines to another file.

```sh
awk '
  BEGIN{srand()}
  FNR==1 {print | "tee f1 f2"; close("f1"); close("f2")}
  FNR!=1 {if (rand() <= 0.2) print >> "f1"; else print >> "f2"}
' my.csv
```

I am using `gawk`. I read the [redirection man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html). I thought that adding `close("f1"); close("f2");` to my first awk action would help, but it doesn't appear to have done anything (the behavior is the same without them).

When I rewrite it to not use `tee`, it *does* work:

```sh
awk '
  BEGIN{srand()}
  FNR==1 {print > "f1"; print > "f2"}
  FNR!=1 {if (rand() <= 0.2) print >> "f1"; else print >> "f2"}
' my.csv
```

**Question**: How do I properly write to a file I've already written to with `tee`?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output then we'll be able to help you. make it clear if you're trying to write said percentage of lines from the head of the input file to the first output file, or from scattered around the input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to modify the `FNR==1` line into something like:

```
FNR==1 {print | "tee f1 f2"; close("f1"); close("f2"); system("sleep 60")}
```

then execute the script and invoke `ps aux | grep tee` from another terminal.
You'll see the `tee` process is still working. It keeps on blocking "f1" and "f2"
from the redirection within the `awk` script.
Please try instead:

```
FNR==1 {print | "tee f1 f2"; close("tee f1 f2")}
```

which safely closes the `tee` subprocess and enables the following redirections.

Answer (score 0):

The second option, without `tee`, is preferred as it does not create an unnecessary process.

You can simplify it a bit more.

```
awk '
  BEGIN{srand()}
  FNR==1 {print > "f1"; print > "f2"}
  FNR!=1 {print > ("f" (rand() <= 0.2 ? "1" : "2"))}
' my.csv
```

Notice, you don't have to use `>>` in `awk` as you do in `bash`.